# How does has_secure_password work in my model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm doing the [Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/), and I've come to the point where you simply add:

```
has_secure_password
```

to your model class and a bunch of magic happens.

I understand that this method comes from the `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` module that is included in `ActiveRecord::Base`, which my model class extends.

What I don't understand is what is going on when I add that one line to my class definition. Can somebody please explain, in as much detail as possible. I really want to understand what is going on and not just throw stuff at my app not knowing how it works.

(If it helps to understand why I'm confused, I come from a Java background and I'm new to Ruby)

Comment: I think that's probably enough of this line of commenting, folks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The easiest way of understanding what anything's doing is to consult the source! In this case, that would be the [ActiveModel::SecurePassword documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html). From that, you can see that `has_secure_password` does this:

```
def has_secure_password
  # Load bcrypt-ruby only when has_secure_password is used.
  # This is to avoid ActiveModel (and by extension the entire framework) being dependent on a binary library.
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
  require 'bcrypt'

  attr_reader :password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of     :password_digest

  include InstanceMethodsOnActivation

  if respond_to?(:attributes_protected_by_default)
    def self.attributes_protected_by_default
      super + ['password_digest']
    end
  end
end
```

To explain in English, this function:

1. Loads the `bcrypt-ruby` Gem and requires `bcrypt`. [bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is a secure hashing function that you can learn more about in Wikipedia.
2. Adds a read-only attribute to the model called `password`.
3. Validates that the password is confirmed by another field, called `password_confirmation`. In other words, you have to enter the password twice to confirm it.
4. Ensures that password_digest is present before a model is saved.
5. Load the [instance methods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation.html), which in this case are `authenticate` (which returns true if the password is correct, otherwise false) and `password=`, which encrypts the passed password into the password_digest attribute.
6. If the method has attributes that are protected by default, this will also add `password_digest` to that list of protected attributes. (Thus preventing it from being mass assigned.)

You can learn more at the [ActiveModel::SecurePassword documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) and the [further documentation on its instance attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/InstanceMethodsOnActivation.html).

Comment: I did take a look at the source before posting. What is confusing me is the `require` and the `include` sitting right in the middle of the method. I come from Java, so when I see `require` my mind says `import` which is only syntactically valid above the class definition in Java. The `attr_reader` sitting in the middle of the method is also a little confusing as well. I went through the Ruby Koans, and don't remember coming across anything like this, but then again I blew through it pretty fast. I seem to be missing something fundamental with Ruby here. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: As opposed to Java, in Ruby you can `require` anywhere in a class to pull in new classes and methods from other sources. `attr_reader` is an accessor: you can read more about them [here](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html) (or just Google for Ruby accessors).

Comment: Yes, but the accessor is declared in the middle of a method, inside of a module that my class includes. Every example I've seen on accessors (including your link) shows their usage as a part of a class definition. I'm not sure how it relates back to the class I'm calling this method in.

Comment: They're actually exactly the same. `has_secure_password` is a class method (when its module gets included in your model). Everything it does is also performed on the class: so when it says `attr_reader :password`, it's exactly the same as including it in your class definition. `attr_reader` is nothing more than a class method itself.